# Inline-block divs fitting 100% width of page if available

Tags: css

Having two divs, the first with an image, the second with text.

Both divs have display:inline-block.
Text div has min-width.

If image width + text min-width fit on page both divs should be on the same line.
Otherwise (as in a mobile browser) text div should go to the next line.

This is working so far, but I can't make text div use 100% of page width and still be to the right of image div.

What I need is that the text div stretch to the full browser width.

```
<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
    <img src="http://www.acasa.org.br/ensaio/grande/506.jpg" style="xmax-width:500px; width:100%; height:auto;">
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;min-width:200px;max-width:500px;background-color:red;">
My text here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:block; float:left;` instead of `display:inline-block;`

Comment: If I use float:left the text will flow around the image. I need the text as a column. This solution is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @fcaserio yeah but that happens when you use image directly with text. In this case you are wrapping both inside a container thus it wont happen. That's why we are using display:block for those container.

Comment: Actually both image and text have their respective container. I'm not sure I get what you mean..